# How to get and set dfiferent IP address for android emulator?

Tags: android-networking

I am very new to Android, my pc's IP is 192.168.1.50.
From the google search I have understood that, default emulator's IP is 10.0.2.2 or any Class A IPs. but our network is working in Class C (192.168.1.50). 
When ever I try to run my application (which is developed to read the emulator IP address) , it is closing automatically by popping this below msg:
"Unfortunately,  has stopped"...
Please help me out in communicating from my android emulator to any other computers or with any other android emulators.
(Looking for any sample code)
Thanks in advance :)